# Why do I have to click button twice to open URL?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have the following code set up to open a URL but requires two clicks to open, any idea's why?

Angular Directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ui.components')
.service('MoreDetailsService', function(){
    return {
        getMoreDetails: function(id) {
            var url = 'https://test.com' + id;

                $('button.more-details-link').on("click",function(){
                    window.open(url, '_self')
                });

        }
    };
})

.directive('moreDetails', ['MoreDetailsService', function(moreDetailsService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            id: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'modules/ui.components/general/views/more-details.view.html',
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {

            $scope.moreDetails = function() {
                return moreDetailsService.getMoreDetails($scope.id);
            };
        }]
    };
}]);
```

Directive view:

```
   <button ng-click="moreDetails()" class="more-details-link btn btn-primary">More product details</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This jQuery click event handler is redundant:

```
$('button.more-details-link').on("click",function(){
    window.open(url, '_self')
});
```

You are using Angular's `ng-click` directive to attach *another* click event to the element. The first time the element is clicked you are attaching the `window.open` functionality via jQuery. Clicking *again* (the second time) then invokes this jQuery event handler.

Simply replace the above with the contents of the jQuery `on` handler. For example:

```
getMoreDetails: function(ean) {
    var url = 'https://test.com';
    window.open(url, '_self');
}
```

Answer (score -2):

HTML:

```
<h1>JQuery Handle Single & Double Clicks on Same Element</h1>
<br />

<h1 id="clickme">CLICK ME ONCE OR TWICE</h1>

<h1 id="result">Result of Click1</h1>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bevan);

body {
  font-family: 'Bevan', cursive;
  background-color: #eddfed;
  margin: 50px;
}

h1 {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: #d7dadb;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

JS:

```
$.fn.singleAndDouble = function(singleClickFunc, doubleClickFunc) {
  // This means it'll take a minimum of 200ms to take the single
  // click action. If it's too short the single and double actions
  // will be called.
  // The default time between clicks on windows is 500ms (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-click)
  // Adjust accordingly. 
  var timeOut = 200;
  var timeoutID = 0;
  var ignoreSingleClicks = false;

  this.on('click', function(event) {
    if (!ignoreSingleClicks) {
      // The double click generates two single click events
      // and then a double click event so we always clear
      // the last timeoutID
      clearTimeout(timeoutID);

      timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {
        singleClickFunc(event);
      }, timeOut);
    }
  });

  this.on('dblclick', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    ignoreSingleClicks = true;

    setTimeout(function() {
      ignoreSingleClicks = false;
    }, timeOut);

    doubleClickFunc(event);
  });

};

var singleClickCalled = false;

$('#clickme').singleAndDouble(
  function(event) {
    singleClickCalled = true;

    $('#result').html('Single Click Captured');

    setTimeout(function() {
      singleClickCalled = false;
    }, 300);
  },
  function(event) {
    if (singleClickCalled) {
      // This is actually an error state
      // it should never happen. The timeout would need
      // to be adjusted because it may be too close
      $('#result').html('Single & Double Click Captured');
    }
    else {
      $('#result').html('Double Click Captured');
    }

    singleClickCalled = false;
  }
);
```